# Caching of json files

Tags: jquery, json

I have a website where I have 13 links. When you click a link, you get a different json file, which displays different data.

One problem is, when the json files are updated, the updates aren't reflected online until you clear your cache or view the json file and refresh it.

The other problem is, the json data that appears for the first link you click then appears for other links that you click.

Any ideas how to solve these issues?

jquery:

```
$('.school').on("click", function() {
    var school = $(this).attr('school');
    $.getJSON( school + "/data.json", function( data ) {
             $('.images').empty();
                         $('.videos').empty();
                          $('.field').empty();

                         var location, enrollment, tuition, history, alumni, fact, prose;
                         location = data.location;
                         enrollment = data.enrollment;
                         tuition = data.tuition;
                         history = data.history;
                         fact = data.fact;
                         alumni = data.alumni;
                         prose = data.prose;


                        $('.location').html('<strong>Location</strong>: ' + location );
                         $('.enrollment').html('<strong>Enrollment</strong>: ' + enrollment);
                          $('.tuition').html('<strong>Undergraduate tuition</strong>: ' + tuition);
                          $('.history').html('<strong>History</strong>: ' + history );
                          $('.fact').html('<strong>Notable fact:</strong> ' + fact );
                         $('.alumni').html('<strong>Prominent alumni</strong>: ' + alumni );
                         $('.prose').html(prose);        
});
});
```

Comment: Without seeing markup I can't help with the 2nd part of your problem, but for the first part simply append `new Date().getTime()` to the filename, use a full blown AJAX call so you can pass `cache: false` as a parameter, or use `$.ajaxSetup` to globally set ajax calls to not cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't change the caching options on the server, you can fix this by making use of the fact that query strings attached to URLs are cacheable. I'm setting `_` to `Date.now()` so that your links will only remain valid for 1ms.

```js
var school = $(this).attr('school'),
    url    = school + "/data.json?_=" + Date.now();
$.getJSON(url, function(data) { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: I think this is correct for clearing the cache. But I continue to have the same problem, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer because it solves any caching issues. I'll continue to seek answers for the problem I'm having.